# How to resolve double printing in my Java factorial program?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        int n = num;
        int result = 1;

        while (num != 1) {
            result = result * num;
            num--;
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + result);
    }
}
```

[image]

I attached the image of my code and output. I just want to not display what I enter to the result.

If I entered number 5 the output should be;

```
Enter No: 5
>20
60
120
The factorial of 5 is 120
```

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
               
        
        int num;
 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        
        
        num = sc.nextInt();
        int n = num;
        int result = 1;
         int k= num-1;
        while(num != 1)
        {
            
            result = result*num;
       
    
                  num--;

        System.out.println(result);
        }
                System.out.println("The factorial of "+ n +" is " +result);
 
    } }

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link and certainly not as an image -- we can't copy and run images. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: And please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36074964/edit).

Comment: Code edited to show proper formatting, making it easier to read and understand. You've got an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the initial value of `result` (and your loop condition). To something like,

```
int n = num;
int result = num;
while (--num != 1) {
    result *= num;
    System.out.println(result);
}
System.out.printf("The factorial of %d is %d%n", n, result);
```

**Explanation**

When you call `result = result*num;` with an *initial* `result` of `1` you get your undesired output of `5` (because `1` * `5` is `5`). If you start with `5` and decrement in the loop test then you'll get `5 * 4`.

**Output**

```
Enter a number: 5
20
60
120
The factorial of 5 is 120
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but the output if i entered 5 should be like this Enter No: 5
Output
20
60
120
The factorial of 5 is 120

Comment: @AikaAlec Edited to correct initial value and add decrement in loop test. It should function as you expect now.

Comment: Youre Great!Thank you it solved my problem thanks :)